# Compute a simple calculation from a timeseries dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, calculation

I have a dataframe with stock price data that looks like this:

```
    Company  Date    Price
0   RSG.AX   2011    0.814 
1   RSG.AX   2010    0.889 
2   RSG.AX   2009    0.937 
3   RSG.AX   2008    0.181 
4   RSG.AX   2007    0.216 
5   RSG.AX   2006    0.494 
6   QBE.AX   2011    7.119 
7   QBE.AX   2010    8.331 
8   QBE.AX   2009    8.961 
9   QBE.AX   2008    9.159 
10  QBE.AX   2007    9.156
```

I want to divide 2009 prices by 2008 prices for each company to see how they changed. However, I can't figure out how to group/isolate each company's data to do this.

Ideally, the end product is a dataframe with the company symbol and its respective computed *price(2009)/price(2008)*.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: post an expected dataframe too for validation :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to divide Price by its previous year value, then you could do as follows.

```py
df = df.sort_values(['Company', 'Date'])
df['result'] = np.where(df['Company'] == df['Company'].shift(), df['Price']/df['Price'].shift(),0)
df
```

```
   Company  Date  Price    result
10  QBE.AX  2007  9.156  0.000000
9   QBE.AX  2008  9.159  1.000328
8   QBE.AX  2009  8.961  0.978382
7   QBE.AX  2010  8.331  0.929695
6   QBE.AX  2011  7.119  0.854519
5   RSG.AX  2006  0.494  0.000000
4   RSG.AX  2007  0.216  0.437247
3   RSG.AX  2008  0.181  0.837963
2   RSG.AX  2009  0.937  5.176796
1   RSG.AX  2010  0.889  0.948773
0   RSG.AX  2011  0.814  0.915636
```

To get ratio of 2009, filter it.

```py
df[df['Date'] == 2009]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this to try not to have to use `apply` which is usually quite slow

```
df_8_9=( df.loc[df['Date'].between(2008,2009)]
           .pivot_table(columns = 'Date',index='Company',values='Price') )
df_8_9['ratio 2009/2008']=df_8_9[2009]/df_8_9[2008]
print(df_8_9)

Date      2008   2009  ratio 2009/2008
Company                               
QBE.AX   9.159  8.961         0.978382
RSG.AX   0.181  0.937         5.176796
```

Comment: How do you then pull out the company names if they are the index? I want to merge it with another series based on company name

Comment: You could use `df_8_9.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only comparison you are interested in, you could groupby each company and then subset to 2009 and 2008 and divide

`df.groupby('Company').apply(lambda x: x[x.Date.eq(2009)].Price/x[x.Date.eq(2008)].Price)`

You could also pivot on your `Date` column and then do the calculation with the columns